# Where is Keras 2 's channels?

Tags: keras

I once used keras 1 (maybe 1.0.5) for multi-category classification. And my input in CNN is (n, 1, 24, 113) and 113 is channel numbers, and kernel size is (1, 5).
code like:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1, 1, SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH, NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, 1, SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH, NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))

# network
inputs = Input(shape=(1, SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH, NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))
conv1 = ELU()(Convolution2D(NUM_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZE, 1, border_mode='valid', init='normal', activation='relu')(inputs))
conv2 = ELU()(Convolution2D(NUM_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZE, 1, border_mode='valid', init='normal', activation='relu')(conv1))
conv3 = ELU()(Convolution2D(NUM_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZE, 1, border_mode='valid', init='normal', activation='relu')(conv2))
conv4 = ELU()(Convolution2D(NUM_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZE, 1, border_mode='valid', init='normal', activation='relu')(conv3))
reshape1 = Reshape((8, NUM_FILTERS * NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))(conv4)
gru1 = GRU(NUM_UNITS_LSTM, return_sequences=True, consume_less='mem')(reshape1)
gru2 = GRU(NUM_UNITS_LSTM, return_sequences=False, consume_less='mem')(gru1)
outputs = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(gru2)

# Hardcoded number of sensor channels employed in the OPPORTUNITY challenge
NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS = 113

# Hardcoded number of classes in the gesture recognition problem
NUM_CLASSES = 18

# Hardcoded length of the sliding window mechanism employed to segment the data
SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH = 24

# Length of the input sequence after convolutional operations
FINAL_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 8

# Hardcoded step of the sliding window mechanism employed to segment the data
SLIDING_WINDOW_STEP = 12

# Batch Size
BATCH_SIZE = 100

# Number filters convolutional layers
NUM_FILTERS = 64

# Size filters convolutional layers
FILTER_SIZE = 5

# Number of unit in the long short-term recurrent layers
NUM_UNITS_LSTM = 128
```

And these days I switched keras to keras 2. and the networks did not change. And my code like:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1, 1, SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH, NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, 1, SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH, NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))

# network
inputs = Input(shape=(1, SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH, NUM_SENSOR_CHANNELS))
conv1 = ELU()(
    Conv2D(filters=NUM_FILTERS, kernel_size=(1, FILTER_SIZE), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='normal', data_format='channels_last')(inputs))
conv2 = ELU()(
    Conv2D(filters=NUM_FILTERS, kernel_size=(1, FILTER_SIZE), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='normal', data_format='channels_last')(conv1))
conv3 = ELU()(
    Conv2D(filters=NUM_FILTERS, kernel_size=(1, FILTER_SIZE), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='normal', data_format='channels_last')(conv2))
conv4 = ELU()(
    Conv2D(filters=NUM_FILTERS, kernel_size=(1, FILTER_SIZE), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='normal', data_format='channels_last')(conv3))
# permute1 = Permute((2, 1, 3))(conv4)
reshape1 = Reshape((SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH - (FILTER_SIZE - 1) * 4, NUM_FILTERS * 1))(conv4)  # 4 for 4 convs
gru1 = GRU(NUM_UNITS_LSTM, return_sequences=True, implementation=0)(reshape1)
gru2 = GRU(NUM_UNITS_LSTM, return_sequences=False, implementation=0)(gru1)  # implementation=2 for GPU
outputs = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(gru2)
```

and the speed seems faster but the shape is strange since I didn't know where is my channels ?

Is there anything wrong with my code and could someone help ? THX

Comment: What do you mean by a strange shape?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko in 2nd code under keras 2, the input shape is (?, 1, 24, 113) and conv1 is (?, 1, 20, 64) and then (?, 1, 16, 64) (?, 1, 12, 113) and (?, 1, 8, 113) and then throw into GRU, and in 1st code under keras 1.0.5 the input shape is (?, 1, 24, 113) and (?, 64, 20, 113) and (?, 64, 16, 113) ... so where is the channels 113 in keras 2 ? did I lost this data ?

Comment: Actually - a default `dimension` setting in `Keras 2.0` is `tensorflow` aka `channels last` version - when channels are stored as a last dimension. In `Keras 1` the default was `Theano` aka `channel first` version. And this is where your confusion comes from.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I know that about the img_dim_order, and my problem is since my channel data seems missed (you can find the input shape is (?, 1, 24, 113) and conv1 is (?, 1, 20, 64)  but previously (?, 64, 20, 113) ) my models runs faster but val_acc actually decreased by 2%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Keras handles the *channel* parameter himself.